# Menu bar active class Smarty template

Tags: javascript, html, css, smarty

I want the menu bar to switch the active class depending on the page it is on instead of only showing home as active, still very new to this thanks =) ( my site has smarty template )

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=4'><span>Photos</span></a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=5'><span>Videos</span></a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=59'><span>Webcam</span></a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=58'><span>Archives</span></a></li>

<li><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/pages.php?id=donate'><span>Donate</span></a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/pages.php?id=join'><span style="color:#EF355C; font-size:20px">JOIN NOW</span></a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.example.com/members/'><span style="font-size:18px">Member Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/tour/images/locky.png"height="22px" width="22px"></span></a>  </li>
```

This is my menu css, not entirely sure you guys might need this but here it is.

```
#cssmenu {
background: #FCB9C5;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul {
list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1;
display: block;
zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
content: " ";
display: block;
font-size: 0;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 15px 25px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: color .25s;
-moz-transition: color .25s;
-ms-transition: color .25s;
-o-transition: color .25s;
transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: -3px;
top: 19px;
height: 6px;
width: 6px;
background: #ffffff;
opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 3px;
width: 0;
background: #333333;
-webkit-transition: width .25s;
-moz-transition: width .25s;
-ms-transition: width .25s;
-o-transition: width .25s;
transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
display: block;
}
 #cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
 display: none;
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 #cssmenu ul li {
 float: none;
 display: block;
 }
 #cssmenu ul li a {
 width: 100%;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
 }
 #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
 #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
 border: 0;
 }
 #cssmenu ul li a:after {
 display: none;
 }
 #cssmenu ul li a:before {
 display: none;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to assign in Smarty selected page.

For example:

```
$smarty->assign('selected_page', 'tour/category.php?id=4');
```

In PHP you could use for this `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable, probably something like this:

```
$smarty->assign('selected_page', substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1));
```

should work fine.

And then in Smarty:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li {if $selected_page eq 'tour/'}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li {if $selected_page eq 'tour/category.php?id='}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=4'><span>Photos</span></a></li>
<li {if $selected_page eq 'tour/category.php?id=5'}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=5'><span>Videos</span></a></li>
<li {if $selected_page eq 'tour/category.php?id=59'}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=59'><span>Webcam</span></a></li>
<li {if $selected_page eq 'tour/category.php?id=58'}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/category.php?id=58'><span>Archives</span></a></li>

<li {if $selected_page eq 'tour/pages.php?id=donate'}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/pages.php?id=donate'><span>Donate</span></a></li>
<li {if $selected_page eq 'tour/pages.php?id=join'}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/tour/pages.php?id=join'><span style="color:#EF355C; font-size:20px">JOIN NOW</span></a></li>
<li {if $selected_page eq 'members/'}class='active'{/if}><a href='http://www.example.com/members/'><span style="font-size:18px">Member Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="/tour/images/locky.png"height="22px" width="22px"></span></a>  </li>
```

**EDIT** Of course it would be much better if you put those menu data into array in PHP using url and anchor text. Then in Smarty you could use loop to display menu and you wouldn't need to write urls twice when you compare `$selected_page` with link url

Comment: Sorry for the newb questions but when you say in smarty or in php what file am I supposed to be editing? all of my menus are in a file called header.tpl  . Also,  Where do I put the smarty assign and server uri?   

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Smarty assign you should put inside PHP file (PHP not TPL) before displaying template file

Comment: Marcin I have to do it inside the tpl its called header.tpl where the menu is and I noticed the person who made this had one that worked except it was pure htlm and they used {literal} commands... I'm giving yours ago now but im putting it inside the header.tpl and the $marty asign in the index.php does that sound right? thank you for everything

Comment: @Eduardof88 That's the way you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

To apply the 'active' class to a different < li > element you should perform a server side changing.

Please take a look at the following page:
http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=60336